# Validating email address

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need this input informs when the user does not use a valid email address.

takes the form gets red border or a message appears (a hover) next to the field

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="simulacaoController">
    <input type="text" ng-class="{red: cadastro.$invalid}" ng-model="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" ng-pattern="mascaraEmail" class="last" required />
</body>
```

AngularJS

```
angular.module("simulacao", []);
angular.module("simulacao").controller("simulacaoController", function($scope){
    $scope.mascaraEmail = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+\.)[a-zA-Z-0-9]{2,3}/";
});
```

CSS

```
.red {
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

My code: https://fiddle.jshell.net/kvxcsync/2/

Answer (score 6):

You could use the input type `email`:

```
<input type="email" ... />
```

[More about input types.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes)

Comment: Very cool.  I was not aware of this myself.   However, just so the OP is aware, it might not be supported in "older" broawsers, specifically IE10. Per : http://caniuse.com/#search=email

Comment: This and other HTML5 form validations don't work in Safari. A polyfill like [webshims](https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim) is required.

Comment: Funniest thing is `a@b` is valid email :p

Comment: @PankajParkar Well, it technically is. Relevant: http://blog.onyxbits.de/validating-email-addresses-with-a-regex-do-yourself-a-favor-and-dont-391/

Comment: @TimoSta I know, but generally it isn't

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS has email validation so no need to use ng-pattern for this

```
<body ng-controller="simulacaoController">
    <form name="myForm">
        <input type="name" ng-class="{red: cadastro.$invalid}" ng-model="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" class="last" required />
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
      Email: <input type="email" name="input" ng-model="text" required>
      <br>
      <span class="red" ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">
        Not a valid email!
      </span>
    </form>
    </body>
```

[Reference link](http://plnkr.co/edit/T2X02OhKSLBHskdS2uIM?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

You have to add input type ="email" and add `<form></form>` Tags for proper form validation

```html
<body ng-controller="simulacaoController">
  <form>
    <input type="email" ng-class="{red: cadastro.$invalid}" ng-model="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" ng-pattern="mascaraEmail" class="last" required />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: It is to automatically detect when the user presses somewhere outside input?

Comment: I disagree this minus vote because ... type='email' itself is an answer ...